# How to preserve complicated excel header formats when manipulating data using Pandas Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am parsing a large excel data file to another one, however the headers are very abnormal. I tried to use "read_excel skiprows" and that did not work. I also tried to include the header in
df = pd.read_excel(user_input, header= [1:3], sheet_name = 'PN Projection'), but then I get this error "ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names." To get around this I tried to name the columns by location and that did not work either.

When I run the code as shows below  everything works fine, but past cell "U" I get the header titles to be "unnamed1, 2, ..." I understand this is because pandas is considering the first row to be the header(which are empty), but how do I fix this? Is there a way to preserve the headers without manually typing in the format for each cell? Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

[small section of the excel file header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u1Fi.png)

[the code I am trying to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwAfJ.png)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import sys
import os
import pandas as pd

#load source excel file
user_input = input("Enter the path of your source excel file (omit 'C:'): ")     

#reads the source excel file
df = pd.read_excel(user_input, sheet_name = 'PN Projection') 

#Filtering dataframe
#Filters out rows with 'EOL' in column 'item status' and 'xcvr' in 'description'
df = df[~(df['Item Status'] == 'EOL')]
df = df[~(df['Description'].str.contains("XCVR", na=False))]
#Filters in rows with "XC" or "spartan" in 'description' column
df = df[(df['Description'].str.contains("XC", na=False) | df['Description'].str.contains("Spartan", na=False))]

print(df)

#Saving to a new spreadsheet called Filtered Data
df.to_excel('filtered_data.xlsx', sheet_name='filtered_data')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the top 2 rows, then:

```
df = pd.read_excel(user_input, sheet_name = 'PN Projection',error_bad_lines=False, skiprows=range(0,2)
```

This has worked for me when handling several strangely formatted files. Let me know if this isn't what your looking for, or if their are additional issues.

Comment: "error_bad_lines=False" returns TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'. I think this is because of the version of panda, but I could be mistaken. When I exclude that, I get KeyError: 'Item Status' which I am assuming is because of "skiprows=range(0,2)" and is no longer identifying the index names. For this to work I have to manually edit the original excel file and put all the important headers in the top row so that it index's the data correctly. I appreciate your help

Comment: Skiprows=range(0,2) works when I unmerge all headers and move them to the bottom most row.  Which is the same as unmerging and moving all of the headers to the top most row without skiprows. I am trying to preserve the format of the headers (including the first two rows), I was told to use openpyxl to merge/ unmerge cells. However I do not know how to do this after `df.to_excel(''filtered_data.xlsx, sheetname='filtered_data', startrow=3)` as the workbook would rewrite that file.